# Get URL Parameter in maplet?

Tags: parameter-passing

I m working with maplet and wanted to get the parameter value of my URL. I know that in maplet if we have a same-named variable in my maplet class but it didnt fill automatically?
what I have done wrong?
I add my maplet class code here.
please help me.

```
package Model;
import org.j2os.shine.maplet;
import org.j2os.shine.jconnection.JDBC;
import java.sql.*;
public class Controller extends Maplet {
String MyURLParameter;

public void initialize() throws Exception{  //change MyURLParameter  }
public void request_method() throws Exception{ //add MyURLParameter to db   }
public void rater() throws Exception{  //close db  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this :

public String MyURKParameter